# Xamarin won't deploy app without crashing

Tags: c#, xamarin

I've tested deployment with the test app hello world as well as my application and nothing will deploy to my devices or to a VM. Here is the output. As soon as the app launches it crashes. I'm not sure if I'm missing libraries or exactly what is happening as this is my first day with Xamarin. Thanks for the help.

```
Forwarding debugger port 8891
Detecting existing process
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MoodTracker_.MoodTracker_/files/.__override__/MoodTracker+.dll
Loaded assembly: Mono.Android.dll [External]
[monodroid-debug] Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,loglevel=0,address=127.0.0.1:8891,server=y,embedding=1
[libc] WARNING: generic atexit() called from legacy shared library
[Mono] Image addref mscorlib[0x66ff49d8] -> mscorlib.dll[0x66ff4018]: 1
[Mono] AOT module 'mscorlib.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/data/MoodTracker_.MoodTracker_/lib/mscorlib.dll.so" not found
[Mono] Assembly mscorlib[0x66ff49d8] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
[Mono] Assembly Loader probing location: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MoodTracker_.MoodTracker_/files/.__override__/MoodTracker+.dll'.
[Mono] Image addref MoodTracker+[0x6707e938] -> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MoodTracker_.MoodTracker_/files/.__override__/MoodTracker+.dll[0x6707dda8]: 2
[Mono] Assembly MoodTracker+[0x6707e938] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
[Mono] AOT module '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MoodTracker_.MoodTracker_/files/.__override__/MoodTracker+.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/data/MoodTracker_.MoodTracker_/lib//storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MoodTracker_.MoodTracker_/files/.__override__/MoodTracker+.dll.so" not found
[Mono] Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MoodTracker_.MoodTracker_/files/.__override__/MoodTracker+.dll'.
[Mono] Config attempting to parse: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MoodTracker_.MoodTracker_/files/.__override__/MoodTracker+.dll.config'.
[Mono] Config attempting to parse: '/Users/builder/data/lanes/1131/62e09eb0/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-armv7/etc/mono/assemblies/MoodTracker+/MoodTracker+.config'.
[monodroid-gc] GREF GC Threshold: 46800
[Mono] Image addref Mono.Android[0x670b3810] -> Mono.Android.dll[0x670b3008]: 1
[Mono] Assembly Mono.Android[0x670b3810] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
[Mono] AOT module 'Mono.Android.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/data/MoodTracker_.MoodTracker_/lib/Mono.Android.dll.so" not found
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref Mono.Android[0x670b3810] -> mscorlib[0x66ff49d8]: 2
[monodroid] Xamarin/Android Trial Mode Active
[dalvikvm-heap] Grow heap (frag case) to 8.247MB for 782912-byte allocation
[libEGL] loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_tegra.so
[libEGL] loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_tegra.so
[libEGL] loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
[OpenGLRenderer] Enabling debug mode 0
[Mono] Image addref System.Core[0x6885e0f0] -> System.Core.dll[0x6885d640]: 1
[Mono] Assembly System.Core[0x6885e0f0] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
[Mono] AOT module 'System.Core.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/data/MoodTracker_.MoodTracker_/lib/System.Core.dll.so" not found
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref Mono.Android[0x670b3810] -> System.Core[0x6885e0f0]: 2
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref System.Core[0x6885e0f0] -> mscorlib[0x66ff49d8]: 3
Loaded assembly: System.Core.dll [External]
[Mono] Assembly Loader probing location: '/MoodTracker+, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.dll'.
[Mono] Assembly Loader probing location: '/Users/builder/data/lanes/1131/62e09eb0/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-armv7/lib/MoodTracker+, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.dll'.
[Mono] Assembly Loader probing location: '/MoodTracker+, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.exe'.
[Mono] Assembly Loader probing location: '/Users/builder/data/lanes/1131/62e09eb0/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-armv7/lib/MoodTracker+, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.exe'.
[Mono] DllImport attempting to load: '/system/lib/liblog.so'.
[Mono] DllImport loaded library '/system/lib/liblog.so'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '/system/lib/liblog.so' ('/system/lib/liblog.so').
[Mono] Searching for '__android_log_print'.
[Mono] Probing '__android_log_print'.
[Mono] Found as '__android_log_print'.
[MonoDroid] Could not load type 'MoodTracker.MainActivity, MoodTracker+, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Skipping JNI registration of type 'moodtracker/MainActivity'.
[Mono] DllImport attempting to load: '__Internal'.
[Mono] DllImport loaded library '(null)'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for '_monodroid_gc_wait_for_bridge_processing'.
[Mono] Probing '_monodroid_gc_wait_for_bridge_processing'.
[Mono] Found as '_monodroid_gc_wait_for_bridge_processing'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for '_monodroid_get_identity_hash_code'.
[Mono] Probing '_monodroid_get_identity_hash_code'.
[Mono] Found as '_monodroid_get_identity_hash_code'.
[Mono] Assembly Loader probing location: '/MoodTracker+, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.dll'.
[Mono] Assembly Loader probing location: '/Users/builder/data/lanes/1131/62e09eb0/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-armv7/lib/MoodTracker+, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.dll'.
[Mono] Assembly Loader probing location: '/MoodTracker+, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.exe'.
[Mono] Assembly Loader probing location: '/Users/builder/data/lanes/1131/62e09eb0/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-armv7/lib/MoodTracker+, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.exe'.
[MonoDroid] UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
[MonoDroid] System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'MoodTracker.MainActivity, MoodTracker+, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
[MonoDroid] at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Type.internal_from_name (string,bool,bool) <0x0003f>
[MonoDroid] at System.Type.GetType (string,bool) <IL 0x00014, 0x0009b>
[MonoDroid] at Java.Interop.TypeManager.n_Activate (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00062] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1131/62e09eb0/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Java.Interop/TypeManager.cs:144
[MonoDroid] at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.46e1b4f7-4f1c-41b7-b3e1-4e33168838db (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00029, 0x0007b>
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for '_monodroid_gref_log_new'.
[Mono] Probing '_monodroid_gref_log_new'.
[Mono] Found as '_monodroid_gref_log_new'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for '_monodroid_gref_log_delete'.
[Mono] Probing '_monodroid_gref_log_delete'.
[Mono] Found as '_monodroid_gref_log_delete'.
```

Here is MainActivity.cs

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace MoodTracker
{
[Activity (Label = "MoodTracker+", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.activity_main);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `Could not load type 'MoodTracker.MainActivity'` is there something special about that class?

Comment: I've included MainActivity.cs

Comment: `[Mono] AOT module 'Mono.Android.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/data/MoodTracker_.MoodTracker_/lib/Mono.Android.dll.so" not found` seems to be your core fail. My suspicion is that you have tried to cause your class or assembly to have a "+" in it. Try spelling out "Plus" rather than using a symbol. Some loaders may try to interpret the "+" as a space. Also check the path. Is "/data/data/" correct? I'm just looking for things that look fishy.

Comment: Please post this as a solution so I can accept it. The + sign was causing compilation errors. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue, as pointed out by @Brian is the `+` symbol at the end of your activity's label. Remove that and it will work.

Comment: The issue will happen with special characters such as á à é... too. (learned the hard way, used an ó without noticing -- Spanish speaking person)